# Where goes thrown exception while getting result of a Future with a timeout set?

Tags: java, exception, concurrency, future

If I run a Future and throw an exception, I got those exception when calling `Future.get` as a `ExecutionException`.

But where goes the thrown exception, if I call `Future.get(timeout)` and the exception is thrown after the timeout is lapsed, like:

```
    Future<String> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println("COMPLETED");
        throw new Exception("ERROR");
    });
    try {
        future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1_000);
```

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: well, it will be thrown and caught on the thread of your executor.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck So, to catch and e.g. log it, I need to implement my own executor?

Comment: No, you just need a `try { } catch ( ) { }` block in your lambda.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing different with respect to exceptions in the two cases you describe.  Consider, for instance, that the asynchronous task represented by your `Future` might terminate by throwing an exception before you ever invoke its `get()` method.  The executor must catch the exception and hold it for you until you do call one of the `get()` methods.

When you call `Future.get(long, TimeUnit)` and the timeout expires, that does not imply that you will never get the result; it just means that you don't get it via that particular method invocation.  Normally you would then either `cancel()` the task or try again later to get the result.

Comment: In fact, if *I* were an `Executor`, I would hold such exceptions by stuffing them into the appropriate `Future` instances.  Then I could just drop all references to those `Future`s and forget about them.